# Unable to extract List elements as integers using `getInfo`

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm using `reduceRegion` to sum the number of water pixels determined by an NDWI. I want to do this on a collection of images to see change in water area over a period time.

The values are returned from the `reduceRegion` in the console and appear to be integers, but I am unable to extract them as such. This seems to be a common problem, but the solution is typically using `getInfo` function to bring these values over to client side. Unfortunately `getInfo` returns a null in this case.

The code below is for a collection of images OR a single image. The single image(`image1`) returns an image with an extra property(`waterArea`), and the mapped algorithm blows up(because the function is returning nulls).

I've also tried using `getInfo` on `waterAg` to potentially bring that list over to client side, however that returns the same `List` of objects that I don't want.

```
var image1 = ee.Image(leastcloud.first()).select(['B11','B8','B3'])

var stackarea = function(image){

  var watermask = ee.Image(0)

  var MNDWI = image.normalizedDifference(['B3','B11'])
  watermask = watermask.where(MNDWI.gt(.31),1);


             //sum of water pixels in an area
  var sum = ee.Number(watermask.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 20,
  maxPixels: 1e9
  }));

  var clientSide = sum.getInfo()
  var setArea = image.set('waterArea', clientSide)
  return setArea

};

var single = stackarea(image1)
print(single)

var watermapped = filterSpot.map(stackarea)
var waterAg = watermapped.aggregate_array('waterArea')
print(waterAg)
```

I'm really not sure how to extract these values as numbers...

I'm hoping to get a list of numbers so that I can concatenate that array to other arrays(date of image, cloud pixel %, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

`reduceRegion` returns a dictionary object, not a number-like object. Therefore, in your `stackarea` function, `clientSide` variable is a dictionary (i.e. an object), not a number.

The number that you're after is stored in the dictionary returned by the `reduceRegion` function. You can get your hand on that number by using a `get` function on this dictionary object:

```
  var sum = watermask.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 20,
  maxPixels: 1e9
  }).get('nd');
```

In this way, `sum` will be a server-side number that store the value you're after (There's no need to use `ee.Number` here as it does not help much).

In case you wonder about why using `get('nd')` but not `get('somethingelse')`, well it's the name of the band in your `watermask` image, and this name is the default band name given to the result of the `normalizedDifference` function.

And in my opinion, you don't even need to use the `getInfo` function which takes much more time to execute. Just delete the line `var clientSide = sum.getInfo()` and modify the next line into `var setArea = image.set('waterArea', sum)`.

Hope this help.